# Python and CSV read works only in one way

Tags: python, csv

I'm doing the following code that read all the line in a CSV file and after, it reads more information about a row chosen by the user.

- This works only the second part `print({rows[2]["Name"]})`

  ```
  with open("file.csv", "r", newline="") as a:
      csv_reader = csv.DictReader(a)
      rows = list(csv_reader)
      for row in csv_reader:  #to read all the line
          x=csv_reader.line_num-3
          print(x, row["Name"])
      print({rows[2]["Name"]}) #to print the information about line 2
  ```
- This works only the first part `for row in csv_reader:`

  ```
  with open("file.csv", "r", newline="") as a:
      csv_reader = csv.DictReader(a)
      for row in csv_reader:
          x=csv_reader.line_num-3
          print(x, row["Name"])
      rows = list(csv_reader) #THIS row changed position
      print({rows[2]["Name"]})
  ```

  And the second part has this error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

How can I solve it? the second part should work because the code alone works.

Comment: Both are wrong. In both cases you're reading the file once (either through list() or a loop) then trying to access rows from the reader again, when it's already at the end of the file. Use only one of the two methods, not both

Comment: When you use `rows=list(reader)` in the first case you load all lines into `rows`. Why not use them? If you want to print the contents iterate over `rows`